# Elastic Search Pick elements from array field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data in the below format in elastic search.

```
{
"fname": "FN1",
  "lname": "LN1",
  "images": [
    {
      "type": "passport",
      "url": ".."
    },
    {
      "type": "full",
      "url": ".."
    },
    {
      "type": "full",
      "url": ".."
    }
    ]
}
```

While fetching data from elastic search, is it possible to selectively pick items from array field, for example, is it possible to include only objects with type="passport" in image array?

Answer (score 1):

[Nested inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits) can come to your rescue, but at the name suggests that data type of the field you are dealing with should be `nested`. Assuming the data type of the field images is `nested`, you can filter based on `images.type` and leverage `nested_hits` to only return matching nested doc.

So the query goes as:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "images",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "images.type": "passport"
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```